# Display Data from database in LIFO manner

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

Is there are any Way To Display Data From Database in LIFO Manner..

Its Default that Data Are Display In FIFO Manner

using id,timestamp we can display data in desc,asc format...

but

without any auto increment field can we  display data in LIFO order, but without it possible or not

Comment: How is your database table structured? The answer is "no" if you don't have a timestamp or auto-increment field in the table.

Comment: i have varchar fields only...

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a field with the creation `timestamp` and sorting your data using that field.

Note that using the id is not a good idea because is not granted that the values will be generated in order, it depends from many factors:

- database used
- if database is executing in a single instance or on multiple servers
- caching algorithms used for generating ids faster

Comment: Also could set `timestamp` to have `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in the database so it can be automatically populated when the record is created.

Comment: Its right that timestamp or any auto increment field can help to display data in Ascending or Descending order, but without it possible or not

Comment: It is possible if you have any other field (or more than one field) that can help in the ordering process. As an example you can have a date (just day month and year) and a progressive inside the day. Or you can have a field representing the year and another field representing a progressive inside the year (not necessary a number), can be for example an alphanumeric string. Or you can have a single field that is built with an algorithm that can be used to sort the items (for example, in Italy the car licence plate).